# How to change animation start/end proprieties via script?

Tags: unity, animation

Is there a way of changing the start/end proprieties (Transform, Rect Transform, etc..) of an animation via script? Like, I have 5 objects that start at the same position but should end in different positions, so I would like to change the end positions of each one via script.

As I haven't found a way to do this, I created 5 animations for this, but I'd like to just have one animation and change its proprieties in runtime.

Comment: It sounds like you might be able to replace this animation with a script that moves the objects to calculated positions, with the endpoint as a parameter. Can you describe the motion you want to perform?

Comment: In this case, I want to translate a Rect Transform from point X1 to X2, making each object have a different X2. In my scene I have other movements similiar but to other endpoints, so I wanted to make them all via script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's possible to be honest, but if you want something completely dynamic, why not make a script that handles the animation itself?

Here's an example:

```
public Vector3 startPosition;
public Vector3 endPosition;

float counter = 1f;

public Update() {

    if (counter <= 0f) {

        // Replace 1.0f with another number to change animation's speed
        counter -= 1.0f -Time.deltaTime; 

        /* Replace `position` with `localPosition`, if you would 
         * like your animation to take place in local space, 
         * instead of world space
         *
         * This is doing linear interpolation, if you would like to do
         * something more fancy, you can tweak `counter`, search for
         * "easing functions" for more info
         */
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, counter);

    }

}

public Animate() { counter = 0f; }
```

Add this in a class, make sure to add additional data like rotation or scale (if you want). Attach the script to any object that you want to animate, then change the `startPosition` and `endPosition` from the Inspector (or from a script, if the object is also made dynamically) for each individual object. Even though all objects are doing the same animation, they are moving to different locations.

Edit:

To support `RectTransform` you use the same logic, but you have to play with its anchor, pivot and position. You can read [Unity's RectTransform API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html), but also make sure to read [Unity: Designing UI for Multiple Resolutions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html), which can help you understand which specific value to animate and why (to appear properly on different screen sizes).

Comment: Would this approach also work with a Rect Tranform? Like, my objects are instantiated in my canvas and the animation occurs. Aside that this will help me with my objects outside the canvas.

Comment: @DanielGuiomarino I edited my answer with more info about `RectTransform`